# Existe diferença na criação de elementos HTML no javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Existe diferença na criação de elementos HTML no javascript ?

**Exemplo:**

Como String:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<h1>foo</h1>';
```

E com createElement:

```js
var elemento_pai = document.body;
var titulo = document.createElement('h1');
elemento_pai.appendChild(titulo);
var texto = document.createTextNode("bar");
titulo.appendChild(texto);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na maioria dos casos, **se o valor do `innerHTML` não vem do usuário**, e está devidamente bem-formado, não há diferença - o resultado será o mesmo.

O maior problema do uso do `innerHTML` é que ele pode ser usado como um [vetor de um ataque de *cross-site scripting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations). Se o valor que você está usando não está "limpo", você pode terminar executando código não desejado. Algumas plataformas explicitamente proíbem o uso do *setter* do `innerHTML`, como por exemplo as aplicações de Windows Store criadas usando HTML/JS.

Os problemas maiores acontecem quando o valor usado para a propriedade vem de uma fonte não confiável (por exemplo, entrada do usuário, ou até um banco de dados cujo valor não foi limpo). Mas se você está ciente do que está fazendo, e o valor vem de uma fonte segura, então teoricamente não há problemas. Mas o fato de ser segura não garante que o seu código não tenha *bugs*, então é possível que mesmo nesse caso o uso do `innerHTML` pode levar a problemas de segurança.

Um outro problema menor é que as funções do document (`createElement`, `createTextNode`, etc.) fazem o escape necessário dos valores que você está usando. Se você quer criar um elemento com um nó de texto com o valor `abc<def>ghi&jkl`, e você usar o `innerHTML`, você terá que se preocupar em escapar os caracteres necessários (`<`, `>`, `&`), o que não é o caso usando as funções do documento. Mais uma fonte potencial de bugs.

Enfim, em vários casos a diferença na criação dos elementos é zero, mas se você usa o `innerHTML` você precisa se preocupar com mais detalhes que se fosse usar as funções de criação de nós do DOM. [Essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29229819/751090) mostra algumas situações onde usar o `innerHTML` pode fazer sentido, mas pessoalmente eu evito o seu uso pelas razões que eu mencionei acima.

Comment: [Nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2305677/4056678) também tem informações sobre o assunto.